# html - ASCII art collapses on a live webpage

Tags: html, ascii

I'm trying to include some form of ASCII art on my work-in-progress website; the art looks fine within the editor (tested with VScode and Sublime Text) but not on the website itself.

I have tried putting it in a `div` and styling it with Roboto Mono, and, following R(oboto) Mono, I decided to try `monospace` on its own. No difference, just a slight change in appearance.
I have also tried putting a `\` before another `\`, as stated in another question I saw here and the result wasn't any different to what happened last time.

How would I fix this?

Code:
[The ASCII that I'm trying to display is within the house div](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3v2Ph.png)

Comment: While the use of `whitespace: pre;` will solve your problem, I’d strongly suggest not posting an ‘under construction’ page, they’re a mostly pointless artefact of the nineties and early two-thousands. One relevant article: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/11/designing-coming-soon-pages/

Comment: Add your original ASCII art into the question as plain text, so others can copy what you are seeing. Your image of text is, frankly, totally utterly worthless here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using `<pre>` tag?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/pre

You should be able to get ASCII art in place...

```html
<pre>
   _    __   ___  _____ _____     _        _       ___       _ _           _   _             
  /_\  / _\ / __\ \_   \\_   \   /_\  _ __| |_    / __\ ___ | | | ___  ___| |_(_) ___  _ __  
 //_\\ \ \ / /     / /\/ / /\/  //_\\| '__| __|  / /   / _ \| | |/ _ \/ __| __| |/ _ \| '_ \ 
/  _  \_\ | /___/\/ /_/\/ /_   /  _  \ |  | |_  / /___| (_) | | |  __/ (__| |_| | (_) | | | |
\_/ \_/\__|____/\____/\____/   \_/ \_/_|   \__| \____/ \___/|_|_|\___|\___|\__|_|\___/|_| |_|
</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```css
.ascii-art {
    font-family: monospace;
    white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<div class="ascii-art">             .,-:;//;:=,
         . :H@@@MM@M#H/.,+%;,
      ,/X+ +M@@M@MM%=,-%HMMM@X/,
     -+@MM; $M@@MH+-,;XMMMM@MMMM@+-
    ;@M@@M- XM@X;. -+XXXXXHHH@M@M#@/.
  ,%MM@@MH ,@%=            .---=-=:=,.
  -@#@@@MX .,              -%HX$$%%%+;
 =-./@M@M$                  .;@MMMM@MM:
 X@/ -$MM/                    .+MM@@@M$
,@M@H: :@:                    . -X#@@@@-
,@@@MMX, .                    /H- ;@M@M=
.H@@@@M@+,                    %MM+..%#$.
 /MMMM@MMH/.                  XM@MH; -;
  /%+%$XHH@$=              , .H@@@@MX,
   .=--------.           -%H.,@@@@@MX,
   .%MM@@@HHHXX$$$%+- .:$MMX -M@@MM%.
     =XMMM@MM@MM#H;,-+HMM@M+ /MMMX=
       =%@M@M#@$-.=$@MM@@@M; %M%=
         ,:+$+-,/H#MMMMMMM@- -,
               =++%%%%+/:-.
               </div>
```